# Need server to call client function ( NO CALLBACK!)

Tags: c#, wcf, client

I've been doing some research on this and I got nothing.
I have a server and client.

My client does request to the server and the server runs some callbacks.
This works fine.
But now, there are some functions from the clients I need to call from the server and are not a result of a client call so I can't use callbacks there.
I'm using WCF and .net 4.0

Any suggestions?

CLIENT:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace WCFClient
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
      CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbacks))]
    public interface IMessageHandler
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void HandleMessage();
    }

    public interface ICallbacks
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void QueuePaths_Callback(string cPath, string EPath, string RPath, string IPath, string OPath);
    }

    public class Callbacks : ICallbacks
    {
        public void QueuePaths_Callback(string cPath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("QueuePaths_Callback: " + cPath);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Callbacks myCallbacks = new Callbacks();

            DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageHandler> pipeFactory =
               new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageHandler>(
                  myCallbacks,
                  new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                  new EndpointAddress(
                     "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

            IMessageHandler pipeProxy =
              pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            while (true)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                pipeProxy.HandleMessage();//send the type for example
            }
        }

        public void IWANTTOCALLTHISFROMSERVER()
        { }
    }
}
```

SERVER:

```
namespace WCFServer
{

    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
       CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbacks))]
    public interface IMessageHandler
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void HandleMessage();
    }

    public interface ICallbacks
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void QueuePaths_Callback(string cPath);
    }
    public class StringReverser : IMessageHandler
    {
        public void HandleMessage()//handle the type and do the request
        {
            ICallbacks callbacks = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbacks>();
            callbacks.QueuePaths_Callback("path1");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
              typeof(StringReverser),
              new Uri[]{
          new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
        }))
            {

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessageHandler),
                  new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                  "PipeReverse");
                host.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Service is available. " +
                  "Press <ENTER> to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                //BLA BLA BLA 
                //CALL IWANTTOCALLTHISFROMSERVER();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to inform the client that something happened on the server?

Comment: Take a look at [ASP.NET SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inform client that something happened on the server you're looking for [Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms731064.aspx).

In full .net you have 2 options for bindings:

- netTcpBinding
- wsDualHttpBinding

netTcpBinding is much better since it doesn't require the client to open port (wsDualHttpBinding does require it).

To be honest the best binding is [PollingDuplexHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.pollingduplexhttpbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that is only available for silverlight. However, it is not that hard to emulate it using basicHttpBinding.

The topic is quite broad so I recommend further reading.

Comment: I was already using DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageHandler> =
                   new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageHandler>(
                      myCallbacks,
                      new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                      new EndpointAddress(
                         "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

Comment: Is there any way to do it this way?

Comment: @AnnArbor87 Ok, and you have CallbackContract and all that stuff? Maybe you should post your code and tell what does not work.

Comment: I think maybe I didn't expain it correctly. I DONT want a callback. I DONT WANT CLIENT calls server and SERVER does callback. I WANT the SERVER to call a function from the client. Just the same way my client calls the server

Comment: @AnnArbor87 Callback is a standard way to achieve this kind of functionality - what is the problem with it? The only limitation is that the client has to make the first call. If you don't want the callback, then the client should act like a server and expose its own service.

Comment: That is what I don't want, I don't want the client to make the first call. I want the service to be able to initiate this.

Comment: @AnnArbor87 so the client has to expose the service - it could be self hosted, however the server must be able to address the client (the client needs addressable ip and open port). The client simply becomes the server, but because the service is self hosted no iis installation is required.

Comment: Any code snippet to help me? So I have to create a pipe in the server and a host in the client? the same way I have it right now but the other way?Thank you, I'm a bit lost

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34393/discussion-between-empi-and-annarbor87)